# Embedding isotopic of the line in the plane

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that two embeddings $f,g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ are always isotopic. 
This problem seems honestly a simple question, but instead I've no idea of what can I do to solve it. 
Also, I can't find a reference of this in no book.

Comment: What do you mean by isotopic?

Comment: Two embeddings $f,g: M\longrightarrow N$ are isotopic if there exists a smooth omotopy $F:M\times\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow N$ such that the maps $F_t:M\longrightarrow N$ are embeddings for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ (where $F_t(p)=F(p,t)$).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late.

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}^2$ be an embedding. Define the isotopy $F_t: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ as $F_t(x) \triangleq \frac{1}{t}\left[ f(0)-f(xt) \right]$ (you can check that this is an isotopy). Then $F_1 \equiv f$ and $$F_0 (x) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{f(0)-f(xt)}{t} =_{s\triangleq xt} x\lim_{s\to0} \frac{f(0)-f(0)}{s} = xf'(0) $$ which is a line ($f'(0)\neq 0$ because $f$ is an embedding) and therefore isotopic to the embedding of $\Bbb{R}$ in the $x$-axis of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Therefore, every embedding is isotopic to $x\mapsto(x,0)$, and in particular all embeddings are isotopic.